# My domain name works without www but not with. Why?

Tags: configuration, dns, vps

I recently linked my Virtual Private Server (VPS) with my domainame (following some tutorials that i found) and it seems to work great but...

It works if i access to http://necarium.com but not http://www.necarium.com

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the domain itself have an `A` record in your DNS setup? Have you told your webserver that `necarium.com` is a valid alternate name for the site? e.g. on apache

```
ServerName www.necarium.com
ServerAlias necarium.com
```

Comment: You need to add 'www' as an alias.